# Installing AzerothCore Build Errors: ace.vcxproj, authserver.vcxproj, worldserver.vcxproj; Builds Skipped: clean_cotire, INSTALL

Tags: installation, ace, azerothcore

I am trying to install azerothcore for the first time, but I am getting stuck building the solution in Visual Studio 2019. As far as I can tell, everything else is working fine. I can post CMake logs if necessary, but that step seems to go smoothly.

When I try to build the solution, 5 things go wrong: 3 projects fail to build, and two skip.

Failures:

1. ace.vcxproj

Output:

```
3>C:\Users\myname\azerothcore\deps\acelite\ace\Process_Manager.cpp(142,1): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
3>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1532)
3> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
3>If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
3>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++

3> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
3>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
3>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
3>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

2. authserver.vcxproj

Output:

```
15>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\deps\acelite\ace\Debug\ace.lib'
```

Notably, in this case, it cannot open the file because there is no file to open. If I navigate to that location, there is no ace.lib. The same error occcurs in

3. worldserver.vcxproj

Output:

```
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\deps\acelite\ace\Debug\ace.lib'
```

Finally, there are the two skips. I am not sure what is going on here (really, I am not sure about what is going on anywhere).

1. clean_cotire

As regards this error, it just says that it was not selected to build. Is this a problem from CMake?

2. INSTALL

Again, it says that it was not selected to build for this configuration.

So that is where I am. I tried finding similar errors on this board, but to no avail. Is there anything I can do about these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You encountered a bug in the latest Visual Studio 2019 release. This has been reported to Microsoft, see [this ACE issue](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/issues/1059) for the link. Please install an older release, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history for the download links.

On May 18th 2020 a [fix](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/pull/1114) for this ICE has been merged into ACE.